# how to insert array of objects in elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, scala, elasticsearch

i have document in ElasticSearch

```
{
    "uuid" : 0,
    "StatusHistoryList" : [
        {
            "ArtWorkDate" : "2015-08-25T16:29:32.011+05:00",
            "ArtworkStatus" : "ACTIVE"
        }
    ]
}
```

i am adding this via code but having problem in adding this array field `StatusHistoryList` 
i am doing it like this

```
var xb:XContentBuilder=XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject()
                        .field("uuid",artWork.getUuid)

      xb.startArray("StatusHistoryList")
      for(h<-history)
      {
        var date=h.date.toString()
        var artworkStatus=h.artworkStatus.toString
        xb.startObject()
        xb.field("ArtWorkDate",date)
        xb.field("ArtworkStatus",artworkStatus)
        xb.endObject()
      }
      xb.endArray()
      xb.endObject()

val bulkRequest=client.prepareBulk()
bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("arteciatedb","artWork",artWork.uuid.toString())
        .setSource(xb)
)
val bulkResponse =bulkRequest.execute().actionGet()
if(bulkResponse.hasFailures())
{
 log.error("something is wrong here ") 
}}
```

on the console it is printing `something is wrong here`
please help me where i am doing it wrong

**UPDATE**
after the answer by **Nimo** here is the output printed on console

```
 controller ERROR - failed to executefailure in bulk execution:
[0]: index [arteciatedb], type [artWork], id [0], message [MapperParsingException[failed to parse [StatusHistoryList]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown property [ArtWorkDate]]; ]
```

Comment: Do you get a more precise error message from `bulkResponse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see where you are doing wrong:

```
var xb:XContentBuilder=XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject()
                        .field("uuid",artWork.getUuid)

      xb.startArray("StatusHistoryList")
      for(h<-history)
      {
        var date=h.date.toString()
        var artworkStatus=h.artworkStatus.toString
        xb.startObject()
        xb.field("ArtWorkDate",date)
        xb.field("ArtworkStatus",artworkStatus)
        xb.endObject()
      }
      xb.endArray()
      xb.endObject()

val bulkRequest=client.prepareBulk()
bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("arteciatedb","artWork",artWork.uuid.toString()).setSource(xb))
try { 
BulkResponse response=currentRequest.execute().actionGet();
 if (response.hasFailures()) {
 logger.error("failed to execute" + response.buildFailureMessage()); }
 } catch ( Exception e) { 
logger.error("Failed to process bulk",e);
 }
}
```

Now the error log would be more accurate and you can understand what's wrong from there.

Comment: I think it's a simple mistake you should change var artworkStatus=h.artworkStatus.toString to var artworkStatus=h.artworkStatus.toString()